# Is there a way to prevent the same alert from firing repeatedly in Azure Application Insights if the conditions haven't changed?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-application-insights, azure-alerts

We are using Azure Application Insights for a project, and I want to stop App Insights from detecting the same problem multiple times in a row, if it's the same piece of data causing the same issue repeatedly:

E.G when posting a data item to a third party API, the data is an incorrect format so the API will reject it, and an Alert will be flagged. The item will return to the top of the queue, only to attempt this again an hour later, resulting in continuous alerts unless the system is shut down.

I don't want to have to answer an alert at every hour of the day, and whilst I understand a code solution would be possible to resolve this, I am hoping that there is a simpler fix that can be made in Application Insights to prevent this from occurring in a more blanket solution.

Comment: Can you provide some more details What you have tried with sample code

Answer (score 1):

In the alertrule details, there is an option for Automatically resolve alerts(preview) which should be enabled not to trigger everytime(frequency of evaluation).

Automatically Resolve Alerts: "Resolve the alert when the condition is not met anymore, and don't fire a new one until it's resolved"